Strange result in \left \middle \right
the code \left(1_Q\middle|\right) gives the result shown below.  Shouldn't the construction \left, \middle, \right produce the parentheses and the vertical bar of the same height?


Can you please provide a complete example?

And in general I recommend you to read Section 4.14.1 ('Delimiter sizes') of https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf. In a nutshell: don't rely on \left etc., use explicit sizing (\bigl, \Bigl, etc.)

My crystal ball tells me that you are using \usepackage{txfonts}. Don't. Put \usepackage{newtx} instead.

It is clearly not the default font. Provide a fill but minimal example that shows this issue and let uers try to replicate it.

Please read: I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?

@campa Your crystal ball seems to be working. However, the result with newtx is no better, but for the simple reason that \left, \right and \middle are wrong in this context.

@campa: Yes, your crystal ball works well. Usually, I use newtx but this was an older file and I was not aware that txfonts was used.@egreg: you are right. With newtx, it is much better but still not ok.  MWE:      `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{txfonts} % or newtx
\begin{document}
$\left(1_Q\middle|\right)$
\end{document}`

@egreg: why is \left, \middle, \right wrong in this (which?) context?

@ThomasS - You may want to start by asking yourself what the purpose of using \left, \middle, and \right is for the expression at hand.

@mico: the goal of this forum is to solve problems, not to challenge people with conundra. Anyhow. When writing formula with brackets and a symbol in the middle, it would be helpful to have a mechanism that ensures that the brackets and the middle symbol have the same size and the stuff in between fits well in. I always thought that's the task of \right, \middle, \left. But now, tell me the solution to your conundrum.

@ThomasS - I apologize profusely for having challenged you with conundra or otherwise bothered you. That was not my intent. To make sure this doesn't happen again, I will just step back, shut up, and not inconvenience you any further. Again, my apologies.

@mico: all good. No need to apologize :-)
